SwiftUI text selection and sheet presentation conflict
I'm developing a SwiftUI application that includes a view displaying artwork details. This view contains several text fields with .textSelection(.enabled) to allow users to select text. However, I'm facing an issue: when I'm in text selection mode and tap outside the text fields, the selection should simply disappear. Instead, tapping outside triggers the opening of a BottomSheetView.
Current Issue:
The BottomSheetView opens every time I tap outside the text fields, even when I'm just trying to exit the text selection mode. I want the text selection to disappear without triggering the BottomSheetView when tapping outside the selection area.
Objective:
How can I modify the behavior so that tapping outside the text fields in text selection mode only dismisses the selection without opening the BottomSheetView?Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated! This version clarifies the issue and your desired outcome, making it easier for others to understand and provide assistance.
public var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text(viewModel.names)
                .textSelection(.enabled)
            Text(viewModel.caption)
                .textSelection(.enabled)
            // Other UI components...
        }
        .onTapGesture {
            // This should open the BottomSheetView
            viewModel.captionViewTapped()
        }


Ensuring the onTapGesture is correctly attached to the parent view.

Searching for solutions related to gesture conflicts with text selection in SwiftUI.



import SwiftUI

extension UIApplication {
    func endEditing(_ force: Bool) {
       self.sendAction(#selector(UIResponder.resignFirstResponder), to: nil, from: nil, for: nil)
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
   @State private var name = ""
   @State private var email = ""

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           Spacer()
           TextField("Enter your name", text: $name)
               .textSelection(.enabled)
               .background(.red)
               .padding()
           TextField("Enter your email", text: $email)
               .textSelection(.enabled)
               .background(.red)
               .padding()
           Spacer()
       }
       .background(.yellow)
       .onTapGesture {
           UIApplication.shared.endEditing(true)
           print("tap")
       }
   }
}

#Preview {
   ContentView()
}

